# Moving files from one directory to others based on the first two letters of the filename using python

Tags: python

First timer here, be gentle :)

I'm very inexperienced with programming in general, and I've been trying to write a python script that will take files from one directory, sort them by the first two letters of the filename, create folders (bearing identical names to the files) for them in different directories, and then move them there.

So if we have three files in the same directory, for example:

1. AB-0000-00
2. AB-0001-00
3. DC-0000-00

I want the first to be moved to a folder created in `dir/` called `AB-0000-00`, resulting in `dir/AB-0000-00/AB-0000-00`.

The second should end up as `dir/AB-0001-00/AB-0001-00`.

The last one has different letters, so I want it to go to `otherdir/DC-0000-00/DC-0000-00`.

I tried writing it a few different ways (using `shutil` to move the files) but had a very hard time handling the file names and couldn't produce code that got any sort of results. My work with lists is also pretty rudimentary, so any help would be very, very appreciated.

Thanks a bunch!

---

EDIT: DNA and DSM advised that I break the problem down into parts and try solving each one individually. This sounded trivial, but it was revelatory, and I managed to write the script all on my own in parts and then merge it together! :)

Metacore provided me with most of what I was asking for originally, so that is also much apprecaited!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is quite broad - you may get a better response by breaking your problem down into pieces (get list of files; sort by first 2 letters; etc) and ask a specific question for that piece (showing your code so far) when you hit a problem, rather than essentially asking us to write your entire program for you.

Comment: One other advantage of breaking the problem down into pieces is that it's a lot easier to find answers to each piece of the question.  For example, searching for "how to get a list of files in Python" (although it sounds like you may have already addressed that part) has lots of hits.

Comment: You could include whatever code you tried and perhaps that will allow others to point out where you could improve.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you wanted?

```
def sort_move(dir):
    files = os.listdir(dir) #stores every filename as a list item ['f1.txt', 'f2.txt'..]
    for name in files: #goes through the list item by item
        folder = name.split('.')[0] #removes extension such as .txt
        os.mkdir(dir + folder) #creates a new dir using filename
        shutil.move(dir + name, dir + folder + '\\') #moves the file to its new folder, deletes old one

sort_move('c:\\test_folder\\')
```

I hope this gets you in the right direction :)